# Solve the equation $x=1-5(1-5x^2)^2$

Tags: real-numbers

Solve the equation
$$x=1-5(1-5x^2)^2$$

###My work

Let $f(x)=1-5x^2$. Then we have tha equation $f(f(x))=x$. But in this case we don't use the equation $f(x)=x$ because $f(x)$ is not monotonic function

Comment: Here's a [SVG graph](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUcFuwyAMvfMV1noIrCRtKlXbhQ_YaZW227RGWaAJEiQMaNpo2r_PpO2kSbsAfn5-ftgHP1gIdasKr5wpvG66ajhGd4ygrRt8hFbFSurgTD1Vtu6R6smZwwQCxtrTLL0zRj56iQjNSw4lI2NtQgpJQvLw6SPdlIytyjVPyPIPgqQrp3y4ca6UG0AY2aEeWjK60bFyZsAk5LC9n_YbEALQBlq4HKQZzODF3eJxfbjjYHSvTlrGTpRJZilgLn-71J_3G7Q8P-kvwlA0R02SdMvVNgXv1w6T1b1I_6zPKohXf1QcWq9lahMETV_nkE7GyGJXhG44UUakRf__zBJTOG_MSVu0vnadbkJ1wK1UoR4VxXq8OHx9c8iKMLYZT8w4ORWK53lRTxZ1XsaWEUyjEMolYoHNKCukagapsMvCed1HGmZi8tRFa-aQ_QCUP5s7&lang=sage) of the relevant functions.

Comment: A related problem is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2866985/solution-to-putnam-2007-a-1

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are on the right track; a modification of your approach will get you the rest of the way.

Let $y = f(x) = 1 - 5x^2$.  Then $f(f(x)) = x$ implies $f(y) = x$, hence the solution to the simultaneous system $$\begin{align} y &= 1 - 5x^2, \\ x &= 1 - 5y^2, \end{align}$$ will yield the desired $x$-values.  To this end, we take the difference to obtain $$y - x = 5(y^2 - x^2) = 5(y-x)(x+y),$$ hence $$(y-x)(5(x+y) - 1) = 0.$$  Then $x = y$ amounts to solving $x = 1 - 5x^2$, which are the "obvious" solutions.  The other set corresponds to $x + y = \frac{1}{5}$, which are the "nontrivial" solutions, and require solving the quadratic $$5x^2 - x - \frac{4}{5} = 0.$$

Comment: +1 for sparing us solving a quartic [the general way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solution_methods).

Comment: Another option is to divide $x-(1-5(1-5x^2)^2)$ by $x-(1-5x^2)$, which gives $25x^2-5x-4$, then solve both quadratics. But your way is nicer. :)